# How to get specific mismatched column when using EXCEPT

Tags: sql, h2

I am using `EXCEPT / MINUS` to compare if rows/columns between two tables are matching.

```
select col1, col2 from table1
minus
select col1, col2 from table2
```

For a given row, if for e.g. `col2` doesn't match, then I would like to output only `col2` ignoring matched `col1` value or show null as there are no mismatches for `col1`.  Is there a way to do that with SQL alone?

Table1

```
| col1 | col2 |
|  A   |  B   |
|  X   |  Y   |
|  M   |  N   |
```

Table 2

```
| col1 | col2 |
|  A   |  Z   |
|  X   |  Y   |
|  1   |  N   |
```

Applying the above sql produces

```
| col1 | col2 |
|  A   |  B   |
|  M   |  N   |
```

But what I might need is only mismatched values as below.

```
| col1 | col2 |
|      |  B   |
|  M   |      |
```

Comment: Please edit your question and (1) provide sample data; (2) desired results; and (3) a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: It currently isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: If that is the case, then **all the time column col1 will be null**. Is there an another scenario that, if **Col1 is not matching**, then **col2 should be null**?

Comment: Yes. Only mismatched values from columns is to be displayed. All matching value in any column can be ignored.

Comment: if both column doesn't match then what should it return? Do you have any other identity column for both table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN T2.COL1 IS NULL OR T1.col1 <> T2.col1 THEN T1.col1 
       END COL1, 
       CASE 
         WHEN T2.COL2 IS NULL OR T1.col2 <> T2.col2 THEN T1.col2 
       END COL2 
FROM   table1 T1 
       LEFT JOIN table2 T2 
         ON (T1.col1 = T2.col1 
             OR T1.col2 = T2.col2)
            AND (T1.col1 <> T2.col1 
                  OR T1.col2 <> T2.col2);
```

Hope this should solve your problem.

Comment: This approach is perfect for my problem